# Excel VBA - Keeping variables the same after End Sub

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have some code that give me some variables - `Champ`. I want to be able to run this programme, then in my next Sub() reference these variables. The code is:

```
  Sub CreateUniqueList()
  Dim dict As Object, lastRow As Long, Champ, c
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
  With Sheets("Raw Data")
      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).row
      For Each c In .Range("D7:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        dict(c.text) = 0
      Next
  End With
  Champ = dict.Keys

  ' Now you have the "variables". To create the new sheet:
  With Sheets.Add(After:= Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    .Name = "Unique Champions"
    .Range("A2").Resize(dict.count).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
    .Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D6").Value
  End With
End Sub


Sub Criteria ()
If (Cells(i, 2).Value = Champ3) Then...............................
End Sub
```

The issue is, when i try to run "Sub Criteria", `Champ3` returns the value Empty.

How can i make it so the variable carries onto the separate programme?

Thanks

EDIT: The second Sub is just there for an example

Comment: Instead of declaring Champ as a local variable with the procedure CreateUniqueList, declare it as a module level variable before any of the procedures.

Comment: This [website](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html) covers variable scope, showing you what @Domenic just mentioned

Comment: So if i just put `Public Champ` before `Sub CreateUniqueList()` it will make that variable available in all Subs?

Comment: USe the `Static` keyword to preserve variables between executions. But note the variables will be cleared upon project reset (pressing the Stop button, for example)

Comment: How would that fit into my code? Tried the `Public Champ` at the top of the code but it didn't work

Comment: Where does `Champ3` get set?

Comment: You'll also have to explicitly run `CreateUniqueList` first before `Criteria` will see a value in `Champ3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing it as a function instead

```
Function CreateUniqueList() As Variant()
    Dim dict As Object, lastRow As Long, c

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    With Sheets("Raw Data")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range("D7:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            dict(c.Text) = 0
        Next c
    End With
    CreateUniqueList = dict.keys
End Function
```

---

```
Sub Criteria()
    Dim Champ As Variant

    Champ = CreateUniqueList

    ' Now you have the "variables". To create the new sheet:
    With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = "Unique Champions"
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Champ)).Value = Application.Transpose(Champ)
        .Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D6").Value
    End With

    If IsInArray(Cells(i, 2).Value, Champ) Then

    End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```